# Cannot use libraries in sub-theme

Tags: 8, theming

I'm experiencing a weird problem. I'm making a sub-theme of the Bootstrap theme that's available for Drupal 8. However, after trying all the possible ways of how to attach a library to a page in my theme, no one seems to work. Am I doin'g something wrong?

Here's my libraries.yml file

```
countdown-timer:
version: VERSION
js:
  js/jquery.countdown.min.js: {}
  js/auction-timer.js: {}
```

Here's how I am trying to attach it to all pages in .info.yml

```
libraries:
  - numisvet/countdown-timer
```

I have already tried the approach of adding `'#attached'` to the render array or using `{{ attach_library('numisvet/countdown-timer') }}` in a twig file.

No one of these seems to work, only libraries defined by the Bootstrap theme are getting loaded.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks a lot for all replies.

Comment: Make sure the yml spacing/indentation is correct. Also, after attaching, clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your library here in your's my libraries.yml file

```
 bootstrap-scripts:
 js:
bootstrap/js/affix.js: {}
bootstrap/js/alert.js: {}
bootstrap/js/button.js: {}
bootstrap/js/carousel.js: {}
bootstrap/js/collapse.js: {}
bootstrap/js/dropdown.js: {}
bootstrap/js/modal.js: {}
bootstrap/js/tooltip.js: {}
bootstrap/js/popover.js: {}
bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js: {}
bootstrap/js/tab.js: {}
bootstrap/js/transition.js: {}
bootstrap/js/transition.js: {}

Your-sub-theme/js/jquery.countdown.min.js: {}

Your-sub-theme/js/auction-timer.js: {}
```

**No need to define it separately also place your js file at correct folder path should be eg:Your-sub-theme/js/jquery.countdown.min.js then clear cache **.